# Is there a 'Power Monitor' for Ubuntu GNOME?

Tags: gnome, software-recommendation, power-management

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 15.10 with GNOME 3.18, and there is one thing lacking, a power monitor tool which will display the status, the one in Ubuntu MATE looks like this:

[image: AC Power Status]

[image: Battery Power Status]

Ubuntu (Unity) also has a similar one, but I can't seem to find one installed by default on Ubuntu GNOME, so is there one that I just haven't found or one that I can install that's made for GNOME, or is not DE specific?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the following power managers in the Ubuntu repositories :

`gnome-power-manager` 
`mate-power-manager` 
`xfce4-power-manager`

These power managers have the design as shown in your screenshots.

Alternatively you can install the `powertop` tool from the repositories.

PowerTOP is a Linux tool to diagnose issues with power consumption and
power management.
It reports which components in the system are most likely to blame
for higher-than-needed power consumption, ranging from software
applications to active components in the system. Detailed screens are
available for CPU states, device activity and software activity.

Additional information -> [Intel Open Source PowerTOP Overview](https://01.org/powertop/overview) |   [PowerTOP User's Guide](https://01.org/sites/default/files/page/powertop_users_guide_201412.pdf)

Tecmint -> [PowerTOP Monitors Total Power Usage and Improves Linux Laptop Battery Life](http://www.tecmint.com/powertop-monitors-linux-laptop-battery-usage/)

Answer (score 4):

The Unity tool is likely from GNOME: `gnome-power-statistics`. The package is named [`gnome-power-manager`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gnome-power-manager), and I think the MATE version is called `mate-power-statistics` (and `mate-power-manager`).